# Python:Contouring around the rectangle object in a image to obtain the corner points of the rectangle

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I have an image which consists of an rectangular object in it and i want to find the 4 corners of the rectangle so that i can calculate the angle of inclination of that object to rotate the image based on that angle.I wanted to know if there are ways to identify the 4 corners of rectangular object so that i can wrap the image using the calculated angle.

I have tried doing some image processing stuff such as converting it gray scale and reducing the noise through Gaussian filter and after which i detect the edge using edge detection filter followed by thresholding and finding the contour.
The problem is that the contours that are found is not consistent and its not performing well on different images from my dataset .Also the background for each of these images is not constant it varies.

Answer (score 0):

Try cv.findContours() on the binarized image, with white object on black background. Then run either cv.boundingRect() or cv.minAreaRect() on the contour.

See Tutorial here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html